# bamboo - build my pull request

Tags: git, bamboo

Im trying to trigger builds in bamboo when a pull request comes into git. I can send the webhook info to bamboo but instead of building the appropriate sha-labeled checkin it just builds the 'master' branch.

Does this require some custom git setup to bamboo? Im not seeing anything straightforward so far.

In my last gig we used Jenkins and it seemed to tie together pretty well. I'm passing the sha-1 to bamboo with the pull request. Now I just need to convince it to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the trick is to capture the id of the pull request from git and use this to checkout the appropriate version from git.

Inspiration from [here](https://blog.oyanglul.us/make%20Bamboo%20support%20Github%20Pull%20Request%20with%20Status%20API.html). I ended up using php to parse the output from the git hook.

Use this to get the right bits from git (on your bamboo box):

```
cd ${bamboo.build.working.directory}
git fetch https://github.com/person/some_util +refs/pull/${bamboo.pull_num}/merge:
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to do same thing but i'm stuck with figuring out how to make bamboo run the build on PR (without the merge). I've created this SO post, think you can share your solution pls? Thanks!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509821/remote-trigger-bamboo-build-from-bitbucket-webhook-only-on-pr

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bamboo spec yaml.

You can use the option  `for-pull-request:` it will run every time a pull request is created or updated.

```yaml
version: 2
plan:
  project-key: PROJ
  key: TASK1
  name: TASK
  description: You description
  master-branch: develop
...
branches:
  create:
    for-pull-request:
      accept-fork: true
```

This is an example of a Bamboo plan configuration written in YAML format.

The `version` field indicates the version of the YAML syntax being used for this file.

The `plan` section describes the basic information about the Bamboo plan. It includes:

- `project-key` and `key` fields, which are used to identify the plan within the Bamboo project.
- `name` and `description`, which are used to display the name and description of the plan within Bamboo.
- `master-branch`, which specifies the default branch used for the plan.

The `branches` section contains settings for branch behaviors:

- `create` creates new branches.
- `for-pull-request` is a specific branch matching pattern that accepts pull request builds.
- `accept-fork` allows for forks of repositories to be built automatically.

These settings will configure how your Bamboo pipeline treats branches when they are created or updated.